# Get duplicate Arraylist(s), placed against each index within an Arraylist

Tags: c#, linq, asp.net-4.0

e.g;

```
ArraylistRoot (0) > (0): id001
                    (1): 10
                    (2): 20
              (1) > (0):id002
                    (1): 10
                    (2): 20
              (2) > (0):id003
                    (1): 11
                    (2): 20
```

I need to compare index 1 & 2 among all Sub-Arraylists and get ids of duplicate records, that i shall delete using some functions from project dlls(which is outside the scope of this question).

Output:  id001 or id002 (not both)

This is what i have done:

```
ArrayList _tablelist = new ArrayList();
ArrayList _rowList = new ArrayList();
 foreach (cClassInstance _row in GetAllList)
                {
                    var s = _row.GetEnumerator();
                    int count = 0;
                    _rowList.Clear();
                    while (s.MoveNext())
                    {
                        var data = _row.GetRawPropertyValue(count++);
                        _rowList.Add(data);
                    }
                    _tablelist.Insert(_tablelist.Count, new ArrayList(_rowList));
                }
```

_tableList Contains all the data as shown in the above example.

Comment: Is three any reason you need to use `ArrayList` in general?

Comment: No, this is just how i proceeded, As far as i get right data in _tablelist, i am ok with using anything else be it; List, etc

Comment: It would be awesome if you could provide a [mcve], including the sample input data.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Pretty unpleasant with ArrayLists, I would certainly convert to strongly typed collections as suggested by Anu if you have to do much manipulation of this data. But working with what you have:

```
            ArrayList tables = new ArrayList()
            {
                new ArrayList() { "id001", 10, 20 },
                new ArrayList() { "id002", 10, 20 },
                new ArrayList() { "id003", 11, 20 }
            };

            var dupes = tables.ToArray()
                    //collect tables into sets with identical [1] and [2] columns
                    .GroupBy(obj => Tuple.Create(((ArrayList)obj)[1], ((ArrayList)obj)[2]))
                    //filter out any sets with only one member
                    .Where(grp => grp.Count() > 1)
                    //return the column[0] for the first member of each set
                    .Select(grp => ((ArrayList) grp.First())[0])
                    .ToList();
```

Comment: This solved the problem however, i would like to try the same thing using Lists (very soon) as @anu has suggested.Appreciate this compact one query solution.

Answer (score 0):

I tried to implemented the flow based on the data you shared in your question. You can still optimize this. I just treid to get results.

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    // PREPARING SAMPLE DATA   
    List<string> duplicateIds = new List<string>();
    List<List<string>> allItems = new List<List<string>>();

    for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++)
    {
        var items = new List<string>();

        for (int j = 0; j < 3; j++)
        {
            if (j == 0)
                items.Add("id00" + (i + 1));
            else if (i == 2)
                items.Add("" + (j * 11));
            else
                items.Add("" + (j * 10));
        }

        allItems.Add(items);
    }

    //PREPARING OPERATIONAL DATA. COVERTING RAW DATA TO DICTIONARY WHICH KEY IS 0TH ELEMENT (ID)
    var allValues = new Dictionary<string, List<string>>();
    allItems.ForEach(l => allValues.Add(l[0], l.Skip(1).ToList()));

    // FINDING DUPLICATE IDS
    foreach (var key1 in allValues.Keys)
    {
        foreach (var key2 in allValues.Keys)
        {
            if (key1 != key2)
            {
                var diff = allValues[key1].Except(allValues[key2]);

                if (!diff.Any())
                {
                    if (!duplicateIds.Contains(key2))
                        duplicateIds.Add(key2);
                }
            }
        }
    }

    //SORTING DUPLICATE IDS AS NEED TO KEEP FIRST INDEX. REMOVING FIRST ITEM AS NEED TO KEEP THAT ITEM
    //THIS IS MOST IMPORTANT PART OF THIS FLOW
    duplicateIds.Sort();
    duplicateIds = duplicateIds.Skip(1).ToList();

    //DISPLAYING ON CONSOLE
    allItems.ForEach(l => Console.WriteLine(l[0] + "=>" + string.Join(",", l)));
    Console.WriteLine("Duplicate IDs =>" + string.Join(",", duplicateIds));

    Console.ReadLine();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you always have two numbers (other than the keystring), you can design your own custom Data structure to hold them. And then, instead of ArrayList, you could make use of List  as well.

For Example,

```
var list = new List<Data>
{
new Data{KeyString="id001",FirstNumber=10,SecondNumber=20},
new Data{KeyString="id002",FirstNumber=10,SecondNumber=20},
new Data{KeyString="id003",FirstNumber=11,SecondNumber=20},
};
```

Where Data is defined as

```
public class Data
{
    public string KeyString{get;set;}
    public int FirstNumber{get;set;}
    public int SecondNumber{get;set;}
}
```

You can now find the duplicate as following

```
var result = list.GroupBy(x=>new {x.FirstNumber,x.SecondNumber}).
                        Where(x=>x.Count()>1);
```

This would return a IEnumerable.

If you are interested only in fetching the first KeyName in the duplicates, you could use following.

```
var result = list.GroupBy(x=>new {x.FirstNumber,x.SecondNumber})
                        .Where(x=>x.Count()>1)
                        .Select(x=>x.ToList().Select(c=>c.KeyString).First());
```

This would return id001 as described in OP.

Comment: This is a nice way to do this, no less a solution however, Christian Water's solution was little more helpful and easy to implement; looking at the scenarios in my project.